# Underline below spinner is not aligning with EditText's Underline

Tags: android, xml, android-spinner

I have been reading posts on SO, and none of the solutions solved my problem.
Im using `style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined` to add underline to the `Spinner` but for somereason the `baseline` of spinner is not aligning with `EditText`.
here is my **XML:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <!-- Phone Country code Spinner -->
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spProfileDetailsUser_phoneNumberCode"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    </Spinner>

    <!--  Mobile Number Label -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="4">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/etProfileDetailsUser_phoneNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="Mobile Number"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

I have tried any solution I found for similar problems on SO trying to align the `spinner` underline with `EditTxt`. However, non helped. such as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940743/issue-with-alignment-using-textinputlayout-and-spinner).

I am looking for solution or workaround to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried applying `android:baselineAligned="false"` to `LinearLayout`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" from your TextInputLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="5"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Phone Country code Spinner -->
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spProfileDetailsUser_phoneNumberCode"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">
</Spinner>

<!--  Mobile Number Label -->
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="4">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/etProfileDetailsUser_phoneNumber"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:inputType="number"
              android:hint="Mobile Number"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of

```
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
```

and you will be fine